# LoadOperation.Completed vs. callback in DomainContext.Load()

Tags: silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

Using Silverlight 3 with RIA: What's the difference between the LoadOperation.Completed event and using a callback through the DomainContext.Load method?  Both fire asynchronously and both provide access to the LoadOperation.  When/why would I use one over the other?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference; the 2 options are offered for flexibility.  Many times, the callback will suffice, but if you return the LoadOperation from a method, the caller could then choose to subscribe.

Note that even if the Load completes before you subscribe to the Completed event, your handler will still get called.  We guarantee every subscriber to the event will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that there is not difference in functionality.  It's about coding style.  If the work I have to do following completion of the query is simple, like binding data to a grid, I like the use the following syntax to inline the completed code, rather than defining a separate method.

```
context.Load<EntityType>(query).Completed += (lo, args) =>
{
   myGrid.ItemsSource = ((LoadOperation) lo).Entities;
}
```

This has the cleanliness of synchronous code, but the code inside the braces will in fact be executed asynchronously.

Good luck!